# Paging with Option/Search Box/Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

I followed this tutorial and created stored procedure for paging
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Custom-Paging-in-ASP.Net-GridView-using-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure.aspx

And soon to realise that all my search/dropdownlist & check boxes stopped working because it was meant for the normal retrieving of data.

may i know how do i implement those option in my paging code/store procedure? 
mine is a web application.

Any samples , would be greatly appreciated